# Destroy object method after first invocation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have already figured out the answer to that, so I am placing it here as a question to myself - for the sake of those that may come up with similar question.

Basically, I wanted to be able to delete an object method. The reason?

I have an action that has to be executed once per object life. This action cannot be placed in the *__init__* method since I need system fully initialized before it is performed.

I have a suitable place holder for that action - a method existing in the parent class. But I would like to be able to avoid checking the condition every time the method is called by framework.

So I tried this approach:

```
In [193]: class Parent(object):
        def place_for_action(self):
           print 'This is parent'
       .....:        

In [194]: class Child(Parent):
    def place_for_action(self):
        super(Child, self).place_for_action()
        print 'This is child'
        delattr(self, 'place_for_action')
   .....:
```

When I tried it, I failed

```
In [186]: c= Child()

In [187]: c.place_for_action()
This is child
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/homes/markg/<ipython-input-187-da53ac96ffa9> in <module>()
----> 1 c.place_for_action()

/homes/markg/<ipython-input-185-7037db53bd87> in do_once(self)
      2     def place_for_action(self):
      3         print 'This is child'
----> 4         delattr(self, 'place_for_action')
      5 

AttributeError: 'Child' object attribute 'place_for_action' is read-only
```

Comment: What? Why can't you do it at the end of `__init__`? What other instantiation is required?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is a complex graphical implementation. The action is to send signals to other components of the system, and there's no guarantee that the components are initialized at the time

Comment: I'm dubious that this is necessary, but it's hard to tell without seeing more of your actual code.

Comment: @chepner, there's such a thing as "existing design constraint". Do you have a better answer to the question? I will be happy to see it.

Comment: I don't because I don't know what your design constraints are, hence my comment rather than an actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

OK, the answer was - delete method at the class level - which suits my need

```
In [195]: class Child(Parent):
    def place_for_action(self):
        super(Child, self).place_for_action()
        print 'This is child'
        delattr(self.__class__, 'place_for_action')
   .....:
```

Works like charm

```
In [196]: c = Child()

In [197]: c.place_for_action()
This is parent
This is child

In [198]: c.place_for_action()
This is parent
```