# writing a method that disables some methods of a class in python

Tags: python

```
    class something(object):
            def __init__(self):
                    pass

            def method1(self):
                    pass

            def method2(self):
                    pass

            def method3(self):
                    pass

            def disable_method12(self):
```

I want to write a method "disable_method12" that disables method1 and method2 in my class but won't disable method3, how can I do this?  shall I write

```
            def disable_method12(self):
                    method1(self) = False
                    method2(self) = False
```

Comment: you cant disable something only `del`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could delete the method like this:

```
    def disable_method12(self):
        del something.method1
        del something.method2
```

or better like this (thanks @volcano) so you can rename your class and it still works

```
    def disable_method12(self):
        del self.__class__.method1
        del self.__class__.method2
```

testing this for `method2` call:

```
s = something()
s.method2()   # first time it works
s.disable_method12()
s.method2()
```

I get at the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'something' object has no attribute 'method2'
```

Comment: Just curious - have you tried declaring *disable_method* as a class method? Either that - or *self.__class__.method1*. Explicitly naming class within its method looks sort of wrong

Comment: good remark, edited. I tried with class & static method and it also works.

Comment: Couple of years ago I had this problem with method I wanted to work once - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913985/destroy-object-method-after-first-invocation

Comment: so this is clearly a duplicate! Closing it. thanks (wouldn't have answered if I knew it was!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre when I tried the self.__class__.method1, I cannot run my code, python gives me a message"can't delete function call"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, not a problem. Just made me feel nostalgic :-)

Comment: @joe, you have obviously placed brackets after _method1_. I tried it with brackets - got the same message at class definition. With brackets, your are trying to delete function call, which is meaningless. Without brackets, you delete **method object** (functions and methods are objects too in Python)